# react full calendar end option is weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Recently using react full calendar. I am not getting the value I want.

The date format entered in 'start' is displayed on the screen as it is.
However, the date entered in 'end' is fixed at 12:00am even if the time changes.

```
  <FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
    dayMaxEventRows={4}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    events={[
      {
        title: 'test',
        start: '2023-03-22T12:00:00',
        end: '2023-03-24T10:00:00',
        color: 'green',
      },
      {
        title: 'test2',
        start: '2023-03-22T13:30:00',
        end: '2023-03-24T14:00:00',
        color: 'orange',
      },
      {
        title: 'test3',
        start: '2023-03-22T09:30:00',
        end: '2023-03-24T11:00:00',
        color: 'blue',
      },
      {
        title: 'test4',
        start: '2023-03-22T14:30:00',
        end: '2023-03-24T12:30:00',
        color: 'red',
      },
      {
        title: 'test5',
        start: '2023-03-22',
        end: '2023-03-24T18:00:00',
        color: 'black',
      },

    ]}
  />
```

[image: 12:00am Image]

All the events have the same end date, but they end at different times in the day.

But on the popup they all show as 12:00am.

I've searched all day and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reasoning behind this is, but it seems like 12:00a is the start time of the events on the last day, not the end time.

You can add `displayEventEnd={true}` as a property on `<FullCalendar />` to display the end times.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-water-xugrui?file=/src/App.js) link.

[image]